# How to stop reading strings from a text file when they are empty

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, text

So, I am using fgets to get strings from a text file into diferent lines of an array, each string is a line. But after all, when I run the program and then write the output to another text file, and it writes the useful strings all correct, but after the last one, since I have to use a define of array lines, with the value 1000, it prints junk, random characters. I tried to have an int that reads the useful strings it reads from the first text file but didn't worked. Also tried to use if(array[line] == '\0') break; didn't work. How do I make it so it stops fprintf after the last useful string? Thank you, this is the code I have to write and to cipher my strings.

```
void cifrar(char texto[MAXLINHAS][MAXCARPORLINHA], unsigned int cifra)
{
    for(int linha = 0; linha < MAXLINHAS; linha++)
    {   
        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < strlen(texto[linha]); coluna++)
        {
            if(texto[linha][coluna] < 'A' || texto[linha][coluna] > 'Z') continue;
            else texto[linha][coluna] = texto[linha][coluna] + cifra;
            if(texto[linha][coluna] > 'Z') texto[linha][coluna] = texto[linha][coluna] - 26;
        }
    }
}

int escreverficheiro(char texto[MAXLINHAS][MAXCARPORLINHA])
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("cifrado.txt", "w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao escrever ficheiro.");
        return (-1);
    }
    for(int linha = 0; linha < MAXLINHAS; linha++)
    {
        if(texto[linha] == NULL) break;
        fprintf(fp, "%s", texto[linha]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return (1);
}
```

Comment: You can count the number of lines read from the file, and use that limit to write them to the other file. And what does the compiler say about `if(texto[linha] == NULL)`, when `texto` is a 2D array?

Comment: @WeatherVane it says nothing. Why would it? :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala my comment says pretty much what your answer says. *And since the array is an existing object, by definition its address cannot be NULL*

Comment: @WeatherVane I am doing a Caeser's Cipher. I read the strings to the array, but to modify each character I need to do it individualy, hence using 2D. Then, after that is done, I can print them line by line as strings like it read on the original file

Answer (score 0):

You have a **2-dimensional array**, not an array of pointers to strings. (well, actually within the function you have a pointer to `char[MAXCARPORLINHA]`, but that points to a 2D array).

```
texto[linha]
```

is an **1-dimensional array of characters**. Except when the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or `&`, an array will be converted to a pointer to the first element.

And since the array is an existing object, by definition its address *cannot be NULL*.

---

The easiest way to do what you want is to pass the number of *lines* as an argument of type `size_t` into the function and not try to use any "sentinel" value.

```
int escreverficheiro(size_t n, char texto[][MAXCARPORLINHA])
```

Comment: But how would I define the size_t argument if I am not allowed to ask the user the ammount of lines the original file has? Is there a way to make it read the files that aren't NULL and then use that value in size_t?